# Payment methods are not visible in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, payment, backend

I am working a vanilla Magento 1.9 setup and trying to set up payment methods.

Once I activate in the backend at System -> Configuration -> Payment Methods they become visible in the frontend, but if I try and place an order through Orders -> Create new order, I cannot choose any payment methods.

I understand that some payment methods have been deliberately programmed to disallow backend payment using the `$_canUseInternal` instance variable for security reasons (e.g. entering credit card details), but picking a payment method such as Bank Transfer should not classify as such. If I look at the implementation in `app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Banktransfer.php` I can see that it doesn't override `$_canUseInternal` which is set to `true` in the abstract superclass.

I have checked the configuration scope in System -> Configuration and it's correctly global/default with no website overrides present.

What am I missing?

Comment: Should be one model class that extends `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` , also make sure config.xml and system.xml both are having same payment methods names

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I am testing the built-in payment methods of Magento. They are already loaded as part of the mage/payment module.

Comment: Not even COD & Bank transfer??

Comment: Correct, I found the answer though from a coworker. I'm adding it now.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out to be inexperience on my part.

**For payment methods to become visible on the backend order page, you must first add products to the order**. When the order grand total is 0, no payment is due and thus no payment methods are available.